# Has window.onload fired yet?

Tags: javascript, domready

I have a script that will be inserted into an unknown page at an unknown time.  Is it possible to tell from this script if window.onload has fired yet?

I have no control over the host page.  I can't add any markup or scripts to it.  All I know is that my script will be inserted into the page at some point.  It could be before window.onload or after; and I need to detect which side of that event I'm on.

Comment: I find the "unknown time" part curious. Is this for a bookmarklet? Dynamic `<script>` inclusion? Seems weird to not know the basic use case for inclusion of your own script...

Comment: It's a dynamic script inclusion.  I simply can't determine if it happens before or after window.onload.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**
[Look at this site.](http://friedcellcollective.net/outbreak/2009/02/19/jqueryreadyordone/) He uses a trick by seeing if the last element of document.getElementsByTagName("*") is defined or not. It seems to work in Opera and IE.

---

**Original Answer:**
You can't check, but you can do:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    // do your stuff
}, 0);
```

That will do your stuff definitely after the page has loaded.

Comment: That will run the function before the DOM is ready in Opera, and may error out in IE. See http://remysharp.com/demo/onload.php for the IE problem.

Comment: Nice find. I want to run that solution through the laundry, see how well it works.

Comment: As explained in the answer, I don't know of a real answer to the OP's question. However, his situation might be helped by my answer, depending on whether the difference between `window.onload` and DOM ready is significant.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery's `ready()` will queue a function to be fired when the document is loaded, or fire immediately if the document is already loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Just be sure jQuery is included before your script block. If you can't include any script resources directly, you can always copy the body of [jQuery-min](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js) in your script itself.

Comment: jQuery as of 1.3.2 cannot detect if the document is loaded if it is itself included after the document has loaded (e.g. bookmarklet, dynamic <script> inclusion, etc), in *non*-IE browsers. In such cases the function passed to `.ready()` will never be called. I'm not sure if the OP is inquiring about such a use-case but just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: jQuery's ready function doesn't appear to work unless it is loaded before window.onload.

Comment: @Diet: in IE it works, as I mentioned. Anyway I take it from your comment that the code you are writing needs to work if included via a dynamic `<script>` tag injected into the DOM? Please clarify.

Comment: OK so here's the bug report for what I described: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4196  Nothing has happened with it for 8 months :(

Comment: The original post asks about window.onload, not DOM ready. -1