# JavaScript onload/onreadystatechange not firing when dynamically adding a script tag to the page

Tags: javascript, events

I am developing a bookmarklet that requires a specific version of jQuery be loaded on the page. When I have to dynamically insert a jQuery script tag to meet the requirments of the bookmarklet I want to wait for the onload or onreadystatechange event on the script tag before executing any function that requires jQuery.

For some reason the onload and/or onreadystatechange events do not fire.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

```
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.type = "text/javascript";
tag.src = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-" + version + ".min.js";
tag.onload = tag.onreadystatechange = function () {
    __log("info", "test");
    __log("info", this.readyState);
};
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tag);
```

**The FULL code:** http://gist.github.com/405215

Comment: See http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4196, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523343/has-window-onload-fired-yet and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526544/document-readystate-analog-for-gecko-based-browsers

Comment: The problem is that I am not seeing onreadystatechange being fired.  The issue I am having is not related to jQuery.

Comment: @spoon16: ahh I misunderstoond. Works for me in FF (2), Chrome 4, IE6. Have you tried `head.insertBefore(tag, head.firstChild)` instead of `appendChild`? You may have markup on the outer page that is conflicting with this style of script inclusion. Or your browser may simply have the file cached?

Comment: On look of your `__log` function, this line will break: `console[type].apply(null, consoleArgs)`. You need to pass the `console` object itself as the first argument to `.apply()`, otherwise nothing will get logged.

Comment: @Cresent Fresh your example is working for me, but I'm not at my dev machine right now so I can't debug my specific problem until I get home.  You should put all this stuff into a proper answer so you can get credit.

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late for you, but here's how I got round the problem.

Basically, it collects the "$(document).ready(function(){})" and "$(function(){})" calls and runs them after jQuery has finished loading.

Instead of using onLoad, we use setInterval to wait for the variable jQuery to become a function after adding the script tag to <head>

```
var $_i, $_r = [];
var $ = function(func){
   if(typeof(func) == 'function'){ $_r.push(func); }
   return{ ready: function(func){ $_r.push(func); } }
}
window.onload = function(){
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
   s.setAttribute('src', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js');
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
   $_i = setInterval(function(){
      if(typeof(jQuery) == 'function'){
         clearInterval($_i);
         for(var i in $_r){
            $_r[i]();
         }
      }
   }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use both events (tag.onload = tag.onreadystatechange), on IE9 it will be called two times.

Answer (score 0):

You could always cheat, and put your onload/onreadystatechange logic into a setTimeout(), specifying a duration of 1 ms.  Since you're inserting the script element into the DOM, you're guaranteed to see it execute before the timeout.

Example code:

```
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.type = "text/javascript";
tag.src = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-" + version + ".min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(tag);
setTimeout(function(){
    __log("info", "test");
}, 1);
```